# Undefined variable: password

Tags: php, html, mysql

Trying to signup with new username and password and get this output - "Undefined variable: password"

```
<?php

    require_once "lib/user_class.php";
    $user = User::getObject();
    if (isset($_POST["reg"])) {
        $login = $_POST["login"];
        $login = $_POST["password"];
        $reg_success = $user->regUser($login, $password);

    }

?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: `$password = $_POST["password"];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no password variable defined, that's why it says `$password` is **undefined.**

Perhaps you meant `$login = $_POST["password"];` as `$password = $_POST["password"];`?  I'm no mind-reader, but I don't think you wanted to create duplicate variables.

Comment: thanks, im junior with code =)

Answer (score 0):

The variable password is not defined..

i have edited your code.

```
<?php

require_once "lib/user_class.php";
$user = User::getObject();
if (isset($_POST["reg"])) {
    $login= $_POST["login"];
    $password= $_POST["password"];
    $reg_success = $user->regUser($login, $password);

}

?>
```